# How do I create a Preference Pane?

Tags: iphone, macos, preferences

How do I create a preference pane for my app on Mac. Also, how do I make a preferences section for my app in the iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your iPhone app needs a Settings bundle if you want to have your preferences in the system preferences.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AppPrefs/index.html

You can create your own preferences view in your app on either platform. This is done by creating a view controller or window controller like you would any other view controller/window controller and you can use NSUserDefaults to store/retrieve the information you obtain from your user.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. I'll check those out.

Answer (score 3):

For the Mac, you may wish to consult Apple's [Preference Panes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/PreferencePanes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000110-SW1) guide.

Answer (score 3):

To put settings inside your application you might want to consider [mySettings](http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/2009/03/mysettings-a-settings-api-for-the-iphone/), an open source (EPL) framework for doing much of the hard work. After making a small code contribution myself I decided against including the setting inside my app after all.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X, i would recommend my [RHPreferences](http://rheard.com/blog/2012/06/rhpreferences/) framework.

Available on [GitHub](https://bitly.com/NxXn1e). BSD Licensed.

Its a simple and easy Preferences window controller with multiple tabs for your next Mac application.

It also provides:

- Auto resizing between different sized tab views (With animation)
- Custom NSToolbarItem support
- Persistence of the last used tab
- Support for placeholder NSToolbarItems (eg NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier & NSToolbarShowFontsItemIdentifier)